# Aligning text and background image

Tags: html, css

Please could someone help diagnose this tiny problem that shouldn't be one -
trying to center-bottom align text below a background image which I've done many times, for some reason can't after hours of trying..

It's the logos floated right in the footer here: http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html

As you can see 'Member Of' is to the left of the image, just below.  here's the inline code for testing:

```
     <div style="margin-right:15px;position:relative;float:right;width:88px;height:100px;background:url(/images/Structure/chamber-logo.png) no-repeat;background-position:50% 0"><span style="font-size:12px;position:absolute;bottom:0;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;">Member Of</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the span to a div:

```
<div style="font-size:12px; position:absolute;bottom:0; width:100%; text-align: center;">Member Of</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`text-align:center` does nothing on the span because its width is the same as it's text. put that style on the outer div instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of this pattern:

http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/svXkt/

I added some background colors, some borders and exaggerated the width of the element containing the logo so as to show that it is centered.

**(1)** You can center the background image by using the `center` value for the `background-position` property.  This is good trick to avoid having to size your container to match the size of the particular logo.

**(2)** The text label/caption is easily centered using `text-align: center;` but this works only on a block level element, hence, use `display: block` when styling the `span` element.

**(3)** `Inherit` the width of the span from the logo's parent container, you need to specify a width.

Of course, as suggested by SpliFF, you could add some padding to the top to move the text inline element down, and then use text-align.

I tend to use this pattern when I have a series of logos on a page, for example, a sponsors page.